# Python Tkinter button

Tags: python, button, tkinter, pressed

```
    refreshButton = Button(frameList, text ="Refresh",command = print("pressed"))
    refreshButton.place(x=50, y=50)
```

Why does this code not print out "pressed" everytime i press the button but only once when the button is created?

There are no error messages. the problem is that print("pressed") does not execute.

Answer (score 1):

use `lambda`:

```
refreshButton = Button(frameList,
    text ="Refresh",
    command = lambda: print("pressed")
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

A button command can't give any parameters unless you use `lambda` or some other function. Instead you need to make your own function to call when the button is pressed.

```
def Refresh(*args):
    print("pressed")
    # do stuff

refreshButton = Button(frameList, text ="Refresh",command = Refresh)
refreshButton.place(x=50, y=50)
```

If all you want to do is `print("pressed")` then this is the alternative solution. `lambda` will catch any parameters given by the button and let you call a function with your own parameters :)

```
refreshButton = Button(frameList, text ="Refresh",command= lambda *args: print("pressed"))
```

Comment: i want to call a function from another object later on. print("pressed") was just a temporary thing to test the button

Comment: Alright, though I don't see why you've added your own answer which is the same as the other two answers...?

Comment: _"... unless you use lambda"_ is not entirely true. There are other ways to pass arguments besides using `lambda`.

Comment: I see, i'll edit that out :)